# Allow users to create folders at netowrk share, but not open others folders

Tags: permissions, network-shares, nas, readynas

I have a ReadyNas Pro4. On it I have created a shares such as "Movies", "Music", "Backup" etc..

### The first step

For these shares I would like to set some (for me) advanced privileges, which brings me to the question:

> *Is it possible to create a share where everybody can see the folders in the root, but only can access the folders they have created
>   themselves?*

Or said in another way:

> *Is it possible to create a folder in which a user can create a subfolder, but not access folders created by others than himself?*

While trying to figure it out on my own, I was able to make a scenario where a user could see the folders in the root, and only open the folder assigned to himself. But this required me to set the permissions manually, and I couldn't get it to work automatically so that a user created a folder, it was locked to him, and only him.

### The next step

To make everything a little more complicated, I would like to allow an administrator account to access and modify/delete anything he wishes to. In the case that somebody should upload material that is not wanted on the share, I want the administrator account to be able to delete said content.

If it makes things easier the admin could be put in the groups "administrators".

Comment: it would be much easier for these folders to be created by an Administrator then have the owner of the folder.  This would allow only the owner and an administrator (obviously) to modify new new folders or files contained within that folder.  "If it makes things easier the admin could be put in the groups "administrators"." - In a general sense this means everyone would have access to everything which is never a good design from an IA perspective.

Comment: I agree, it sure would. That's also the solution that I found when tinkering around with it myself. I was just wondering of it was possible to do the way described